# How can I execute command line program with ./ via a Python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, executable, pythonpath

I have a program in a directory ~/trevor. Using Ubuntu, if I cd to this directory then I can execute this program with 
`$./program`

However, I want to be able to execute this program from within a Python script, but when I try using

```
import subprocess.run
subprocess.run("./program")
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How can I solve this?

I am running the python script through Pycharm's terminal. It has occurred to me that I could run the python script through Ubuntu's terminal, but then I have a problem with Ubuntu finding the correct packages. I am running Windows with a Ubuntu shell - I tried solving the Ubuntu package problem by changing Ubuntu's PYTHONPATH to the same path as Pycharm's project interpreter, but this didn't work either. I thought it would be easier to solve the problem above than to the package problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's not a Ubuntu error, it's a Windows error. This is clearly not an Ubuntu-native copy of Python. Use the Linux version of Python on your Windows+Ubuntu system, not the Windows one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your comment. Indeed, running the python script from my Ubunutu terminal solves the subprocess.run("./program") problem, though a problem remains that my Linux shell doesn't know where to find my python packages and hence the rest of the script can't run. I have tried changing the PYTHONPATH to where the packages seem to be installed, though this doesn't seem to cover all packages and hence the script still fails. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any Python packages that include (or pull in a dependency that includes) native C modules you'll need to install twice, one for each platform. I'd suggest keeping two different virtualenvs.

Comment: Thanks Charles, you are correct. I have done this and it works.Cheers!

Comment: I'm moving that solution from a question-edit to a community-wiki answer, as described in the [meta.se] post [What to do when OP answers his/her own question in an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit). ("Community Wiki" means nobody gets reputation points from votes/acceptance, and anyone/everyone is encouraged to make edits that improve the answer). That way, you can accept the answer and thereby mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0):

As [previously discussed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328011/how-can-i-execute-command-line-program-with-via-a-python-script#comment110262225_62328011), and then included in an [edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62328011/2):

The mistake was trying execute a Ubuntu program through a Windows command line. The solution here was to execute the Python script (with `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.call()`) through the Ubuntu command line.

Insofar as executing Python on Ubuntu can't find Python packages/modules, this is because those packages/modules were installed through the Windows command line, so native/compiled dependencies they included were built for Windows rather than Ubuntu. Even if Ubuntu's PYTHONPATH is pointed to the location of the packages, there are some modules that won't work because they have platform-native components. The solution is to download the package again but through Ubunutu (such that they are suitable for a Linux distribution).

Answer (score -1):

os.exec* typically works for both windows and linux as far as I'm aware, however it does require an a letter or two that replace the "*" in certain situations. You'll have to look at this to see which one you would need https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
ex. os.execl or os.execle

subprocess.call is an older version that will avoid a lot of the problems with shell specific conventions. If the issue is Ubuntu-nativity as the comment above suggests, this could fix it.

Comment: All of these run the same syscalls underneath and so will be prone to the same error when trying to invoke a binary for a different platform.